# Add development Category to every SendGrid message

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, sendgrid

We're using SendGrid for emails in our Asp.Net 7 web application. We'd like to add in a "development" category when sending emails during development. There is a method to add categories to an email at the time that we are sending any message and we can certainly do that for every message in the system, but is there a way to configure the SendGrid client with default category when we first add it as a DI service so it's present in every single message?